# On the nature of infinite sequences of digits?

Tags: real-analysis

I am given the following question. Let $\Sigma = \{ (a_n) \mid \{ a_n \} \subseteq \{ 0, 1 \} \}$. Define the metric $d((x_n), (y_n)) = \sum 2^{-i} |x_i - y_i|$. Prove that $\Sigma$ is compact.

It is not hard to show that every sequence $\{ a_n \} \subseteq \Sigma$ has a Cauchy subsequence. The idea is, we can find a subsequence $a_{n_1}$ such that the first digit is “eventually” $0$ or $1$. Then, we can find another
subsequence $a_{n_2}$ such that the second digit is “eventually” $0$
or $1$. Repeat the step, we should find a convergence point.

However, I find the proof unsatisfactory since I cannot take for granted that $\Sigma$ is complete, neither can I prove it directly. To make my proof precise, what I obtain is merely that for any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find a $p_{\epsilon}$ such that there is a subsequence that is $\epsilon$-close to $p_{\epsilon}$. Unfortunately, this cannot show that the sequence converges, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here are two questions:

1. I notice that rational numbers are not the set of all infinite decimal sequences with a dot somewhere in it, since rational numbers have periodic decimal expansion. How is this related to completeness of a space? Can we prove completeness from this perspective?
2. How can I show that $\Sigma$ is compact without proving that it is homeomoprhic to the Cantor set?

Comment: Can you pick out a periodic-digit subsequence from any cauchy sequence? Surely it's possible since there are only 10 digits.